Clothing glitching out in pose mode, despite transferring mesh data and parenting to rig
I modelled clothing for a rigged and animated character:

Then, following a tutorial, I transferred my character's mesh data to the 1st item of clothing (coat), then parented the coat to character's rig, and when I switch the rig to Pose mode the coat DOES adjust like it's parented, but SOMETHING is up bc it has turned into something that looks like it belongs on a high-fashion runway show which unfortunately is at odds with the Victorian Man Vibe I am aiming for

Side-note, I literally can't remember how I got the shirt to follow the rig, I don't recall having to transfer mesh data, but it's working
I'll re-watch more tutorials on it but if anyone more seasoned knows the solution, do share! :)
